# Using alias column in ORDER BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I create an SQL query to group with having value and sorting records by alias, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `timeline`, 
       (SELECT Max(mycountview) 
        FROM   (SELECT Count(id_timeline) AS mycountview
                FROM   `timeline` 
                WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
                GROUP  BY mediaid)AS mycountview)AS max_mycountview
WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
GROUP  BY mediaid 
HAVING Count(id_timeline) < max_mycountview
ORDER  BY max_mycountview DESC 
LIMIT  0, 5
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Unknown column 'max_mycountview' in 'order clause'

How to fix it?

Comment: you can use index(1 based) of column. so if `max_mycountview` is column number 2 then write `order by 2`

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the subquery to the `select` statement instead of the `from` clause:

```
SELECT *, 
        (SELECT Max(mycountview) 
        FROM   (SELECT Count(id_timeline) AS mycountview
                FROM   `timeline` 
                WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
                GROUP  BY mediaid)AS mycountview) AS max_mycountview
FROM   `timeline`
WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
GROUP  BY mediaid 
HAVING Count(id_timeline) < max_mycountview
ORDER  BY max_mycountview DESC 
LIMIT  0, 5
```

---

Actually after rereading your query, I don't believe that would be the most efficient approach.  Your query is performing a `cross join` between the tables.  However the subquery isn't correlated -- it returns the same value for every column.  In this case, you just need to define the column name in the subquery to be able to access it in the `having` and `order by` clauses:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `timeline`,
       (SELECT Max(mycountview) max_mycountview   <!--Define Column Alias Here
        FROM   (SELECT Count(id_timeline) mycountview
                FROM   `timeline` 
                WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
                GROUP  BY mediaid) t) y
WHERE  type_timeline = '1' 
GROUP  BY mediaid 
HAVING Count(id_timeline) < max_mycountview
ORDER  BY max_mycountview DESC 
LIMIT  0, 5
```